# How I create a bitmap from a matrix with matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, bitmap

I want to create a bitmap with MATLAB. It is juste a white image with a red rectangle in a very specific location as you can see in the code. In fact I get the red rectangle but I didn't find out how to obtain the White color outside the rectangle.

```
x=0:9;
y=0:17;
matrice=zeros(17,9,'uint8');
for i =1 :length(x)
    for j= 1 :length(y)
        if (i>=3) && (i<=6)&&(j>=2) &&(j<=16)
            matrice(j,i)=56;
        else matrice (j,i)=248;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html

Comment: What function you use for drawing this? `image`? `imagesc`?

Answer (score 0):

You're code seems to be missing a lot of stuff. Please double check that you copied everything correct.

A very quick way of doing what you want would be like this:

```
% create matrix
matrice=zeros(17,9);
matrice(2:16,3:6)=1;

% Plot matrix
imagesc(matrice)

% Color matrix
colormap([1 1 1; 1 0 0])

% Fix axis
axis square
```

The function `imagesc` will create an image where each index of the matrix is represented by a pixel. The data is scaled to fit into the current colormap, therefore by setting the current colormap to white and red only you get your red rectangle with white background.